How to append string to array inside a few objects of a JSON file in Node.js
I am making a Node.js server that stores JSON files with complex data, and I'm having trouble appending a string to an array deep into the JSON file.
Node.js code block:
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("send dm", (dm_user_id, user_id, message) => {
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "data", "users", `${user_id}`, `${user_id}.json`), "utf-8", (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err

            let parsed_data = JSON.parse(data)

            parsed_data.user.app_data.sent_messages = parsed_data.user.app_data.sent_messages + `, ${message}`

            fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, "data", "users", `${user_id}`, `${user_id}.json`), JSON.stringify(parsed_data), "utf-8", (err) => {
                if (err) throw err
            })
        })
    })
})

JSON file:
{
    "user": {
        "username": "boyninja15_",
        "id": "boyninja15_",
        "password": "128",
        "avatar": "https://example.com/avatars/0.png",
        "app_data": {
            "received_messages": {
                "Not_Me_Again": [
                    "Hi there!"
                ]
            },
            "sent_messages": {
                "Not_Me_Again": [
                    "Hi there back!"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}


I tried other posts, but they had simpler problems that I did not have.

What error are you getting? What is not working? Since user.app_data.sent_messages is array, try push method instead of concatinating strings.

The main issue with your NodeJS code is the following line:
parsed_data.user.app_data.sent_messages = parsed_data.user.app_data.sent_messages + `, ${message}`

It appears that you are trying to append a string to an array, but you're using the + operator which is meant for string concatenation. When you want to add an element to an array in JavaScript, you have to use the .push() function. On top of that, you have separate arrays for each user stored inside an object where the keys are the user ID - so you need to access the array of messages via that user ID.
Here's how your code would look with those changes:
parsed_data.user.app_data.sent_messages[userId].push(message);

